# Convert Contour into BLOB OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, blob, contour

Hi everyone,
              I am trying to convert a contour to a blob in an image .There are several blobs in image ; the proper one is extracted by applying contour feature. The blob is required to mask a grayscale image.

I have tried extracting each non-zero pixels and pointPolygontest() in order to find the BLOB points, but it requires >70ms to complete the proccess. The application is in 30 fps videos, so I need to convert them within 30ms. I am using OpenCV in python.  Is there a way to convert a contour into a Blob within 30ms in opencv?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of programming, I realized the procedure is:

1. After a contour is extracted, create a black image with same size as the original image.
2. Draw the contour in black image.
3. Find the coordinate of the contour center by contour feature : moments, x0 and y0.
4. Use `Floodfill()` to white-fill the interior of the contour using (x0,y0) as seed point.

The resulting image contains the white BLOB to the corresponding contour.